# how to check a login value correctly in php and mysql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a database containing username and password. The username is in lower case.However when i type in uppercase it still login. How to fix that error.

Comment: Show us some code. (or use strtolower() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your database probably is using the default collation, which is case-insensitive.

either define your username column with case-sensitive collation, or explicitly pass that collation in your SQL query.

example:

```
SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE username = '<username>' AND password = '<password>' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```

here is the mysql documentation for your reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing the username with the user input, then you must use a case-sensitive string comparison function.

For example, if you have stored the username in a table called `info`, and you get the user-entered value through a form post, then your code should look something like

```
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "root") or die ("Sorry! There was an error.");
$db = mysql_select_db ("myDB", $con);
$cmd = "select username from info";
$res = mysql_query ($cmd);
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($res);
if (!strcmp ($row['username'], $_POST['username']))
  {
    //code to handle event where entered username matches.
 }
else
  {
   //code that handles the event when entered username is not on the list.
 }
```

Alternatively, you can use `==` or `===` as @kallum has said.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score -1):

The login function will just be checking for a matching string. If you need an EXACT match (same capitalization) then instead of, for example:

```
if (loginName == databaseName)
```

use:

```
if (loginName === databaseName)
```

The triple equals symbols should make sure to match the case of each character.

Comment: php already does case check triple `=` is for value and object type.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. Thought this was the same in all languages, my apologies. Without any code, we won't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`==='$username' AND `password`='$hashed_password'"
it's not work !

Comment: Right, so it's the SQL where you have a problem? You didn't post any code, I assumed that problem was with the PHP. I think one or two of those terms may be SQL reserved words, try putting square brackets around "id".